# dart typedef subclass function fails

Tags: dart, subclass, typedef

I have a function signature

`typedef ActionFunc =  void Function(SamModel sm,SamReq req);`

I have a class that subclasses SamModel

`class Rocket extends SamModel {`

Here is the failing code

```
  void lightRocket(Rocket r,SamReq req) {
    ...
  }

  void addFunc(String str,ActionFunc af) {
   ...
  }

  ... 

  addFunc("func-name",lightRocket); //<--- fails at this point
```

This above fails with Dart saying:

'''type '(Rocket, SamReq) => void' is not a subtype of type '(SamModel, SamReq) => void'``

When I recode lightRocket as:

```
  void lightRocket(SamModel sm,SamReq req) {
    Rocket r = sm as Rocket; // Can i get rid of this?
    ...
  }
```

it works.  I have many functions to add like `lightRocket` and would like to eliminate the cast operation. Is this possible using generics or some other trick?

Comment: The linked question is asking the same thing with different parameters. Your typedef says that the function will accept a `SamModel`. But when you restrict your function to only taking `Rocket`s, it is no longer valid when taking other `SamModel` arguments. If you make another class that extends `SamModel`, your typedef says the function should be able to take it, but `lightRocket` would be unable to do so because you restricted it to only `Rocket`s.

Comment: This sentence from the above link helped. Thanks.

Note that this is not specific to method overrides. In general, a function that takes a narrower type cannot be used where a function that takes a wider type is expected, even if the narrower type derives from the wider type.)

I will try the covariant keyword.

Comment: Perfect. covariant did the job.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is:

```
void lightRocket(covariant Rocket r,SamReq req) {
    ...
}
```

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/13250142/christopher-moore